# Правильное построение запроса на открытие приложения для построения маршрута

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Помогите пожалуйста решить проблему. 
Задумка такая, нужно получить ссылку (которую потом я преобразую в qr код). При сканировании которой происходит вызов приложения Яндек.Карты на устройстве и построения маршрута от текущего местоположения (т.е. нужно определить текущее местоположение человека) до точки Б (ее координаты заданны и не изменны).
Почитал документацию от яндекса для разработчика. 
Тут https://tech.yandex.ru/yandex-apps-launch/navigator/doc/concepts/navigator-url-params-docpage/ есть пункт Построить маршрут из текущей точки (yandexnavi://build_route_on_map?lat_to=55.70&lon_to=37.64), а тут (https://tech.yandex.ru/yandex-apps-launch/maps/doc/concepts/yandexmaps-android-app-docpage/) описывается возможность вызова приложения для построения маршрута между точкой А и точкой Б (yandexmaps://maps.yandex.ru/?rtext=55.745719,37.604337~55.76009,37.648801&rtt=mt).

Вопрос в следующем. Можно ли через yandexmaps://maps.yandex.ru/?rtext=55.745719,37.604337~55.76009,37.648801&rtt=mt не задавать начальную точку А координатами, а в определять координаты точки А из текущего местоположения человека?
Если можно, то подскажите как это можно реализовать.

Надеюсь на вашу помощь.

Answer (score 1):

Url-схема позволяет только то, что явно описано в документации. То есть как-то параметрами передать, что точка А - местоположение пользователя, нельзя.

При этом в самом приложении мобильных Яндекс.Карт есть логика: если точка отправления не задана, то за неё автоматически принимается местоположение пользователя.

В вашем случае это будет такая ссылка:

```
yandexmaps://maps.yandex.ru/?rtext=~55.76009,37.648801&rtt=mt
```

Минусы этого подхода в том, что есть небольшой риск, что логика приложения поменяется или местоположение пользователя недоступно на устройстве, но тогда пользователь просто сам заполнит адрес точки А в приложении.